# Strange Linq Error

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am using Linq to convert an array of any object to a CSV list:

```
String.Join(",", (From item In objectArray Select item.ToString()).ToArray())
```

This is giving me the strange error: ***"Range variable name cannot match the name of a member of the 'Object' class."***

I can get round it by wrapping the string in a VB StrConv method, with a setting of "Nothing":

```
String.Join(",", (From item In oArray Select StrConv(item.ToString(), VbStrConv.None)).ToArray())
```

However, this seems like a bit of a hack and I would like to avoid it.

Does anyone have any ideas when this problems occurs, and any better ways to get round it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Modify your code to:

```
String.Join(",", (From item In objectArray Select stringVal = item.ToString()).ToArray())
```

The problem is VB gives a name to the variable returned by `Select` clause. Implicitly, it tries to give the name `ToString` to `item.ToString()` which will clash with `ToString` method. To prevent so, you should explicitly specify a name (`stringVal` in above line).