# Why can't I project ToString() in VB?

Tags: vb.net, linq

If you try to compile the query below in Visual Basic .NET, it fails.

```
From x In {1, 2} Select x.ToString()
```

The error given by the compiler is:

> Range variable name cannot match the name of a member of the 'Object' class.

There is nothing wrong with the equivalent C# query, though:

```
from x in new[]{1, 2} select x.ToString()
```

This does not happen with the `ToString` overload that takes a format (it is a member of Int32, not Object). It does happen with other members of Object, as long as they don't take an argument: with GetType and GetHashCode it fails; with Equals(object) it compiles.

Why is this restriction in place, and what alternatives can I use?

Comment: Interesting. `From x In {1, 2} Select x.ToString("d")` does compile, probably because `Object` doesn't have it. I don't know any VB though, but it looks weird.

Comment: @Kobi: I guess your example compiles because there's no `ToString` member in `Object` that takes an argument. Why that would be a problem is what puzzles me.

Comment: I think it's because it's obviously not a property when invoked with an argument, and therefore VB knows you're not using it to create an anonymous object with a 'ToString' property - whereas it someone gets it wrong otherwise. (Which might have been what you were saying - I'm not a VB expert.)

Comment: @Rup: that makes some sense, because VB is somewhat schizofrenic about properties and no-args methods. But the syntax for anonymous methods is not ambiguous. Furthermore, this does not happen with no-args methods that are not in Object. (I'm not a VB expert, either, I'm more of a C# guy)

Comment: On connect : http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/366012/compiler-error-in-vb-linq-query-expression

Comment: I've found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598445/strange-linq-error , with a weird workaround - `From x In {1, 2} Select dummy = x.ToString()` . Conclusion: C# is awesome.

Comment: From x In {1, 2} Select dummy = x.ToString() works in VB, which is just as awesome

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's how I understand it. Consider the following code:

```
Dim q = From x In {"Bob", "Larry"}
        Select x.Length
        Select Length * 2
```

In the query above, the name of the `Length` variable is *automatically* "guessed" for you by the VB compiler based on the expression `x.Length`. Now, it's true that you didn't *ask* for this; it's just a feature that's provided whether you like it or not. But now consider this:

```
Dim q = From x In {"Bob", "Larry"}
        Select (x.Length)
        Select Length * 2
```

The above does not compile because the expression inside the first `Select` clause is not as simple as in the first case (believe it or not); the parentheses complicate matters just enough for the compiler not to pick the name `Length`; instead, it generates a name that is not usable from code.

So basically what's happening with `ToString()` is that this expression is simple enough for the compiler to use to generate a variable name, which *could* be used if the query were expanded to make use of this variable, e.g.:

```
Dim q = From x In { 1, 2 }
        Select x.ToString()
        Select ToString.Length
```

However, `ToString` is not a legal name for a variable since it is a member of `System.Object` (why this would be the case for variables within LINQ queries but not for standard local variables, I couldn't say).

Comment: Gosh, I hate this feature. I see how it can be useful, but the problem it creates is mindboggling and my example is far from being a rare use case. I don't see how a insightful error message could be provided, but I think the compiler should automatically "not-guess" the name if it was not a valid name.

Answer (score 38):

I couldn't tell you exacly *why* VB has this ridiculousness, but the simple workaround is to put the method call in parens.

```
Dim q = From x In {1, 2} Select (x.ToString())
```

Comment: Thanks tnyfst.I have made implemented a suggested code improvement from resharper but it suddenly throwing error.then i put the parenthesis as suggested by u and it works greatly.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

While I can't offer details about the error, a simple workaround it:

```
From x In {1, 2, 3} Let str = x.ToString() Select str
```

For what it's worth, when you have the following line:

```
Dim b = From num In {1, 2, 3} Select num.ToString("d")
```

it is compiles and decompiles to (using Reflector, to C#):

```
public class Class1
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private static string _Lambda$__1(int num)
    {
        return num.ToString("d");
    }

    public void Test1()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> b = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }
            .Select<int, string>(new Func<int, string>(Class1._Lambda$__1));
    }
}
```

There doesn't seem to be any anonymous class along the way.