# Linq to xml multiple group by clause

Tags: linq-to-xml, grouping

After reading many posts about LINQ to XML and many trials using grouping I have now formated the following LINQ query:

```
    Dim objList = (From i In xmlDoc.Descendants("payment_amnt")
                   Group CType(i.Value, Decimal)
                   By Key = i.Parent.Element("account_id").Value.ToString() Into g = Group
                   Select New With {.ItemName = Key, .Sum = g.Sum()}).ToList()
```

I would like to add another group key ("payment_mnth") but when I do this:

```
    By Key = i.Parent.Element("account_id").Value.ToString(), Key = i.Parent.Element("payment_mnth").Value.ToString() Into g = Group
```

I get errors.

How do i add a second group key to this query?

Thanks in advance.

Stephen

PS: After Davids feedback i have added the following into linqpad and get this error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Dim xmlDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("c:\\Backup\PAYMENT.xml")

Dim objList = (From i In xmlDoc.Descendants("payment_amnt")
               Group CType(i.Value, Decimal)
               By AccountId = i.Parent.Element("account_id").Value.ToString(), PaymentMonth = i.Parent.Element("payment_mnth").Value.ToString() Into g = Group
                Select New With {AccountId, PaymentMonth, g.Sum()}).ToList()


objList.Dump()
```

It seems to be the AccountId in the 'By' part causing the error. My XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PAYMENT xmlns="urn:lst-emp:emp">
  <PAYMENT xmlns="">
    <id>1</id>
    <paymentdate>17/06/2013</paymentdate>
    <payment_no>1</payment_no>
    <payment_to_id>1</payment_to_id>
    <PAYMENT_TO>PWA</PAYMENT_TO>
    <payment_type_id>1</payment_type_id>
    <PAYMENT_TYPE>Computer Services</PAYMENT_TYPE>
    <payment_request>Stephen</payment_request>
    <payment_amnt>100</payment_amnt>
    <comment></comment>
    <payment_checked>0</payment_checked>
    <GST>9.09</GST>
    <payment_month>Jun</payment_month>
    <account_id_transfer />
    <account_id>1</account_id>
  </PAYMENT>
  <PAYMENT xmlns="">
    <id>2</id>
    <paymentdate>17/06/2013</paymentdate>
    <payment_no>2</payment_no>
    <payment_to_id>1</payment_to_id>
    <PAYMENT_TO>PWA</PAYMENT_TO>
    <payment_type_id>1</payment_type_id>
    <PAYMENT_TYPE>Computer Services</PAYMENT_TYPE>
    <payment_request>Stephens</payment_request>
    <payment_amnt>1000</payment_amnt>
    <comment></comment>
    <payment_checked>0</payment_checked>
    <GST>90.91</GST>
    <payment_month>Jun</payment_month>
    <account_id_transfer />
    <account_id>1</account_id>
  </PAYMENT>
  <PAYMENT xmlns="">
    <id>3</id>
    <paymentdate>17/06/2013</paymentdate>
    <payment_no>3</payment_no>
    <payment_to_id>1</payment_to_id>
    <PAYMENT_TO>PWA</PAYMENT_TO>
    <payment_type_id>1</payment_type_id>
    <PAYMENT_TYPE>Computer Services</PAYMENT_TYPE>
    <payment_request>Stephen</payment_request>
    <payment_amnt>145</payment_amnt>
    <comment></comment>
    <payment_checked>0</payment_checked>
    <GST>13.18</GST>
    <payment_month>Jun</payment_month>
    <account_id_transfer />
    <account_id>1</account_id>
  </PAYMENT>
</PAYMENT>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing in your attempt you have put account_id in both Keys...

Also what is the "Key" object? As far as I know you do not need this and that might be the source of some of your errors

Can you try the following:

```
By i.Parent.Element("account_id").Value.ToString(), i.Parent.Element("payment_mnth").Value.ToString()
```

EDIT: Ok I think that this is part due to me not being familiar with VB. I see what "Key" was for now so you can ignor that if you like.

The reason for your error can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4647477/1341477

To correct it you can do as follows:

```
By AccountId = i.Parent.Element("account_id").VAlue.ToString(), 
   PaymentMonth = i.Parent.Element("payment_mnth").Value.ToString() Into g = Group
Select New With {AccountId, PaymentMonth, g.Sum()}
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting the error of my copy and paste. I tried this but I got the error: Range variable name cannot match the name of a member of the 'Object' class.

Comment: Using LinqPad I have created a new query and it still errors. I have added query and XML above.

Answer (score 0):

All of this led to the following

```
Dim xmlDoc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("c:\\Backup\PAYMENT.xml")

Dim objList = From item In xmlDoc.Descendants("payment_amnt")
               group CType(item.Value, Decimal)
               by Key = item.Parent.Element("account_id").Value.ToString(), item2 = item.Parent.Element("payment_month").Value.ToString() into g = Group
                Select New With { .acc_id = Key,.p_month = item2, .Sum = g.Sum() }


objList.Dump()
```

Thanks Dave for the help. Would not of got here without it.

Comment: Glad you got there in the end :) I was using LinqPad as well but don't have your data so maybe not exactly the same. If I helped you are welcome.