# How to Convert C# Linq to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

can someone help me convert this C# Linq-u to a VB.NET code

```
var groupedItems = from item in LinqueResult
                    orderby item.Category
                    group item by 
                        item.GetType().GetProperty("Test").GetValue(item).ToString()
                        into groupPropertie 
                    select new KeyedList<string, ItemToDisplay>(groupPropertie);
```

Thanks

UPDATE:

ken2K i know but i dont get a working code with the online converters

I got it on my own to this point

```
Public Function GroupedPhotos(LinqueResult As List(Of ItemToDisplay), GroupMember As [String]) As List(Of KeyedList(Of String, ItemToDisplay))

    Dim groupedItems = From groupPropertie In From item In LinqueResult
                                              Order By item.Category
                                              Group item By item.GetType.GetProperty(GroupMember).GetValue(item).ToString() Into Group
                                              Select New KeyedList(Of String, ItemToDisplay)(groupPropertie)

    Return New List(Of KeyedList(Of String, ItemToDisplay))(groupedItems)
End Function
```

And i get this error:

> Error 1: Range variable name cannot match the name of a member of the 'Object' class. C:\xxx\MainPage.xaml.vb 53 118 LongListSelectorFreeLancVBasic

Comment: Sorry, you have websites that do this job automatically, stackoverflow is not here for this kind of tasks.

Comment: Perhaps, but I doubt you find someone on SO. Please show us what you have tried yourself first.

Comment: I was wrong, there are some people that just convert things for you, you lucky....

Comment: @ken2k Please show me just one online converter that doesn't totally suck at converting linq queries and lambdas and produces code that actually compiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Online converters suck. The correct translation is:

```
Dim groupedItems = from item in LinqueResult
                   order by item.Category
                   let test = item.GetType().GetProperty("Test").GetValue(item).ToString() 
                   group item by test into groupPropertie = Group
                   select new KeyedList(Of string, ItemToDisplay)(groupPropertie)
```

Note that you have to use a `let` clause to bind the result of the `item.GetType()...ToString()` to another name. Otherwise, VB.Net tries to create a local variable named `ToString` and then complains about `ToString` can't be used because there's a member on `Object` with this name.

Using a `let` on this long line makes it easier to read IMHO.

The `group` syntax is also different: to use a named group, you'll have to use `your_group_name = Group`. But since you actually don't do anything with `groupProertie`, you could as well just use

```
...
group item by test into Group
select new KeyedList(Of string, ItemToDisplay)(Group)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim groupedItems = From groupPropertie In From item In LinqueResultOrder By item.CategoryGroup item By item.[GetType]().GetProperty("Test").GetValue(item).ToString()New KeyedList(Of String, ItemToDisplay)(groupPropertie)
```

Comment: This one comes from the Developer Fusion tool at http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/. Most reliable converter out there IMO.

Comment: First, spaces are not added at some position and Second, even if added it doesn't work

Comment: Does not even compile. This line is so full of errors I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

stick the compiled version into any decompiler ([DotNetPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/%E2%80%8E), [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx%E2%80%8E), or reflector) then ask it to show you the code in VB

Comment: +1 since this answer does provide an answer. I do the same, I simply cannot understand why this question was downvoted...

Answer (score 0):

The link stuff is pretty much the same, except for vb.net typically uppercases the keywords:

```
Dim groupedItems = From item In LinqueResult
                    OrderBy item.Category
                    Group item By item.GetType()
                        .GetProperty("Test")
                        .GetValue(item)
                        .ToString() 
                    Into groupPropertie 
                    Select New KeyedList(Of String, ItemToDisplay)(groupPropertie)
```

Comment: The ToString() part gives me the same error as in my code

Comment: Sorry ... i just wrote it off the top of my head, as I don't have access to vb.net right now. 

Here is another question that adresses that particular problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646724/why-cant-i-project-tostring-in-vb