# Linq query that returns Ids as List(Of String)

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have tried several casts and can't get this to work.
Here is what I am trying to convert into a linq query in vb.net:

The Ids are of type int

```
Dim listOfProductIds As New List(Of String)
For Each s In Products
    listOfProductIds.Add(s.Id)
Next
```

This is what isn't working when I expect it to:

```
Dim listOfProductIds As List(Of String) = (From s In Products
                                           Select s.Id.ToString()).ToList()
```

Comment: There's no query there - you haven't described what's wrong, either. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: `Products.Select(function(p) p.Id.ToString()).ToList()`?

Comment: Just Call ToString on s.Id

Comment: Please see my recent update.

Comment: Carsten the code you gave me works perfectly, but how come what I am trying above in the added linq query does not?

Comment: Duplicate of [Why can't I project ToString() in VB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646724/why-cant-i-project-tostring-in-vb)

Comment: Read all the answers in the dupe link and you'll end up with this: `(From s In products Let id = s.Id.ToString() Select id).ToList()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not following what you are trying to do but converting `int` to a `string` is straight forward.

```
Dim listOfProductIds As New List(Of String)
For Each s In Products
    listOfProductIds.Add(s.Id.ToString())
Next
```

Comment: The code works like this but I am trying to figure out how to do it in a linq query.

Comment: listOfProductIds = (from p in Products select p.Id.ToString).ToList()

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the value like this because we can't project the `ToString()` function to a `LINQ` variable.

```
Dim _ids = (From p In products Select Convert.ToString(p.Id)).ToList
```